# Get keyboard device ID for key event on UWP window when using multiple keyboards

Tags: uwp, raw-input, deviceid

Currently I have a Win32 desktop program written in C++ that uses the [Raw HID Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/inputdev/raw-input) API (a message loop observing [`WM_INPUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-input) messages) to read key events and also get a handle to the specific keyboard that produced the event. I need this information to change the behavior depending on the keyboard when I use multiple keyboards.

Now because developing a nice Win32 GUI seems a pain to me, I'd like to use a UWP UI. I tried [KeyRoutedEventArgs.DeviceId](https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.input.keyroutedeventargs.deviceid) but this is always an empty string (`""`). Maybe this is because it is only supported on Xbox?

The alternative would be to use the Raw Input API again, but the first problem I'm running into then is: can I even obtain window messages from a UWP window? And if so: is it possible to combine this with the Raw Input API to receive `WM_INPUT` messages?

To be clear: I don't need the program to be on the Windows Store or anything, I would just like to have a nice UI. But maybe (probably?) this is not possible in this way :/

Something which I just thought of is to try to globally listen for events by using [`RIDEV_INPUTSINK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-rawinputdevice#RIDEV_EXINPUTSINK) when the UWP app window is focused, but this is a mild hack and I hope there is a better and easier way like the `DeviceId` property would be.

Answer (score 0):

Great question, I'm afraid you could not distinguish multiple keyboards when typing in UWP app. I found you have used win32 api to detect the keyboards successfully, with help of desktop-bridge, you could use the same way in UWP platform . In other words, you could make desktop extension for uwp app, and send the different keyboard info to main uwp app with [AppService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service). And Stefan has a blog that explain how to use desktop extension to detect global hot key. You could google **Global hotkey registration in UWP** for the detail.